# Python web scraping using BeautifulSoup, how to loop through complicated URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape Florida Statutes from this website : www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/

So far I have only able to scrape the frist chapter:
http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0001/0001.html.

I noticed that the url change to "URL=0000-0099/0002/0002.html." as I jump to next chapter. My question is, how do I code in a way that I can scrape all the chapters? (the first part of URL 0000-0099 is range of the chapters, so this case it would be from 1st to 99th chapter)

my codes are below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

f = open('C:\Python27\projects\outflieFS_final.txt','w')

def First_part(url):
  thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,'html.parser')
  return soupdata

soup = First_part("http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0001/0001.html")

tableContents = soup.find('div', {'id': 'statutes' })

for data in tableContents.findAll('div'):
   data = data.text.encode("utf-8","ignore")
   data = str(data)+ "\n\n"
   f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a loop and use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to form the url:

```
base_url = "http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/00{chapter:02d}/00{chapter:02d}.html"
for chapter in range(1, 100):
    url = base_url.format(chapter=chapter)
    print(url)
    # make a request and parse the page
```

This would produce the following urls:

```
http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0001/0001.html
http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0002/0002.html
...
http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0098/0098.html
http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0099/0099.html
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, your code is changing the range of the chapters. I want to change the part 0001/0001 to 0002/0002 for second chapter, 0003/0003 for third chapter and so on.

Comment: @TianMa okay, updated, assuming you want to leave the range as is.

Comment: thanks! it worked. A offtopic question, when I write the output to a txt file, how come it print out my output three time with different format? is it something wrong with my "for" statement?

Comment: @TianMa glad to help. Please see if it makes sense to create a separate question about this next problem - this way more people can theoretically help. Make sure to provide all the details. Thanks!

Comment: As I browse the site, I noticed that it has chapter 1-2 then it jumps to 6-8, then 10 -11, as some of the chapter are not included. For your range argument (1,100) i was about to do (1,3). but was not able to do (1,4) as chapter 4 page (0004/0004) does not exist. do I have to manually input all the ranges?  Thanks!